# How to set up authentication layer in node.js app using ntlm

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, windows-authentication, ntlm

How to setup authentication in node.js application using ntlm ?
node.js is serving the webpages that need to be authenticated for windows user only, using ntlm. How to set up this authentication layer ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the passport module https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport with the windowsauth strategy https://github.com/auth0/passport-windowsauth

Comment: Any tutorial to refer ?

Comment: I do not know of a tutorial that shows use with NTLM.

Answer (score 0):

Use the express-ntlm package if you are using Express. No passwords to deal with on your end.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ntlm